# Compile Tor with self compiled openssl

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openssl, tor

I'm trying to get Tor running with a self compiled version of OpenSSL (compiled with enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128)
I've configured OpenSSL with `./config enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl`. I try to configure Tor with `./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl` but I always get

```
checking for openssl directory... configure: WARNING: Could not find a linkable openssl.  If you have it installed somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-openssl-dir
configure: WARNING: On Debian, you can install openssl using "apt-get install libssl"
configure: WARNING:    You will probably need libssl-dev too.
configure: error: Missing libraries; unable to proceed.
```

How must I configure Tor to use my custom OpenSSl version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: I compiled OpenSSL with

`./config enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 shared zlib-dynamic --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl`

and then Tor with

`./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl --enable-static-openssl`